# Looping through IWebElements elements and comparing with IList string

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

My DOM elements:

```
<ul id="testList" class="sc-ksdxgE jiDfgt" xpath="1">
  <li class="sc-hBUSln fPSRnx">Carp and its Derivatives</li>
  <li class="sc-hBUSln fPSRnx">Tilapia and its Derivatives</li></ul>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to:

a) Get main element (testList) or get main element element's (li)

```
private readonly string allergensDoesContainListLocator = "//ul[@id = 'testList']//li";
public IList<IWebElement> AllergensDoesContainList => driver.FindElements(By.XPath(allergensDoesContainListLocator));
```

b) Create list of element which I want to pass & assert:

```
IList<string> DoesContainAllergens => new List<string>(new string[] { "Carp and its Derivatives", "Tilapia and its Derivatives" });
```

c) Write proper loop method
I was thinking about simple LINQ something like:

```
AllergensDoesContainList.Where(c => c.Text == allergensToCheck)
```

Or ForEach statement

```
          //allergensToCheck.ForEach(delegate (string name)
                  //{
                  //    bool isAllergenVisible = driver.IsElementVisible(By.XPath(string.Format("//div[@data-automation='sizePanel[{0}]'][contains(.,'{1}')]", sizeIndex, name)));
                  //});
```

Can someone advice me what will be the perfect way? Using NUnit for a unit test provider, if that helps.

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: using the Nunit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves two main steps. First, collect all of the text into an `IEnumerable<string>`. Next, use the [CollectionAssert](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Collection-Assert.html) class in NUnit to make your assertion:

```
private readonly string allergensDoesContainListLocator = "//ul[@id = 'testList']//li";
private IList<IWebElement> AllergensDoesContainElements => driver.FindElements(By.XPath(allergensDoesContainListLocator));

private IEnumerable<string> AllergensDoesContainList => AllergensDoesContainElements.Select(element => element.Text);
```

Now you can make your assertion:

```
var expectedAllergens = new string[]
{
    "Carp and its Derivatives",
    "Tilapia and its Derivatives"
};

// If the order on screen matters to your assertion:
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedAllergens, AllergensDoesContainList);

// If the order on screen does not matter:
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedAllergens, AllergensDoesContainList);
```